# Automatic background updates via HTTP on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, background-process

I'm creating an iPad application and I require following functionality:

> Whenever the application is running (eg. in background or foreground),
>   make a periodical (eg. once an hour) check to some HTTP(s) and
>   possibly download and store some data.

The motivation behind this is to allow the application to cache some data, so that they are available offline when needed. I'm aware that this can decrease battery life, but that is not an issue now.

From what I've read there [Apple iOS Programming Guide: Background Execution and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20), it is possible for an application to perform background tasks. I was not able to find a case suitable for my needs:

- Executing a Finite-Length Task in the Background: this is only for "going to background from foreground" tasks.
- Scheduling the Delivery of Local Notifications: Obviously not the case, I'm creating any notifications, I just need to download some data.
- Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks: This seems like a catch, but when explored, it has several categories and I didn't find any to cover my use case (copy paste from apple.com):

  - `audio`—The app plays audible content to the user while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content using AirPlay.)
  - `location`—The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it is running in the background.
  - `voip`—The app provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection.
  - `newsstand-content`—The app is a Newsstand app that downloads and processes magazine or newspaper content in the background.
  - `external-accessory`—The app works with a hardware accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the External Accessory framework.
  - `bluetooth-central`—The app works with a Bluetooth accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the Core Bluetooth framework.
  - `bluetooth-peripheral`—The app supports Bluetooth communication in peripheral mode through the Core Bluetooth framework.

How should I proceed when implementing this feature? Is it even possible in iOS?

I'm using 6.0.1 or 6.1 iOS and 4.6 XCode.

Edit: First thing I thought of was the newsstand-content, but deeper in the referred document there is:

> When your server sends a push notification to indicate that a new issue is available, the system checks to see whether your app has the UIBackgroundModes key with the newsstand-content value.

but I need PULL requests, not push (the iPad has to ask the server, not the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

You don't, this will run the battery down very fast and there for Apple does not wan't you to do this. Apple is against a PULL request to a server every so often. There is also no need.

As you have summed up, there not one of the background categories that you app falls in to.

You should only update the apps data when ever the user decides to open your app, only then would it be a good moment to update the data.

If there is a really need to inform the user of new data, you should implement push notification. This is the way to inform the user that the app wants there attention. If the opens you app via the notification you can update the data and even present the user with the select notification data.

Just imagine that the user opens your app once, then never looks at it again, you app will still be updating. Use battery and bandwidth which it should be using.

Comment: rckoenes: I'm well aware of disadvantages of such approach due to batt/data consumption. However, this is a B2B application and it is possible that we will be expected to implement such updates (whether it drains the battery or not). So, my question remains, is there a way to do it? Or it is absolutely impossible in iOS and only alternate solution are push notifications?

Comment: No there is no really solutions, since the iOS will not allow you to keep running in background.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally poll for data often when the application is active and trigger an update behind the scenes when the application becomes active again. Having the app poll regularly when active will give you less data to download when the app becomes active.

Personally if I had an application that I knew was draining my battery I would delete in an instant. It may just be me but I look out for things like that.

The other way would be to use notifications alerting the user that there is new content so when the application has new content a notification is sent then when the user selects this notification they are aware that content may need to be updated.

Hope that makes sense and a lot of it is opinionated